# How to determine one-class SVM's $r$ parameter after obtaining $\alpha$ from QP programming solver?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm reading about one-class SVM in wiki here: [One-class SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification). One-class SVM attempts to learn $r$ and $c$ to fit a hypersphere to the dataset. The formula for assigning labels is:
$$sign(r^2 - ||\phi(x) - c||_{2}^2)$$, where $\phi$ is transform training set $x$ to higher-dimensional space

But I am not really sure about how one could obtain the $r$ parameter from $\alpha$.

This is the optimization problem to solve for $\alpha$:

$$max(\sum_{n=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}k(x_i, x_i) - \sum_{n=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}\alpha_{j}k(x_i, x_j))$$, subject to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{n}\alpha_{i} = 1, 0\leq\alpha_{i} \leq \frac{1}{vn}$$

And $c$ is obtained from:

$$c = \sum_{n=1}^{n}\alpha_i\phi(x_i)$$.How about $r$? How are we supposed to calculate?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the expression with $r$

Comment: @Sycorax I'm asking explicitly about the expression of $r$ :<. There's no formula found in the given link

Comment: This question is not possible to answer without a meaningful description of what $r$ is and how it relates to SVM.

Comment: Sorry. I did manage to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. This can be searched quite easily. I was quick to open a question. I'm gonna answer this for anyone needing an answer.

Samples with $0< α_i<1/ νn$ lie on the sphere boundary, and samples with $α_i=1/νn$ lie outsidethe sphere, i.e., are outliers. The samples with non-zero $α_i$ are called support vectors (SVs) since they are suficient todescribe the center as defined in expression (4). In practice,only a very small fraction of the data are SV. Let $I_{sv}$ be the set of indices associated to SV, namely:

$$i \in I_{sv}, 0< a_i < 1 /vn$$

So the optimal $r$ is:  $\min_{i\in I_{sv}}(\Vert\phi(x_i) - c\Vert_2).$

Reference:
Noumir, Zineb & Honeine, Paul & Richard, Cedue. (2012). [On simple one-class classification methods.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261248728_On_simple_one-class_classification_methods) IEEE International Symposium on Information Theory - Proceedings. 2022-2026. 10.1109/ISIT.2012.6283685.

Comment: This is very similar to how $b$ is resolved in standard SVM. The non-bound support vectors are classified as $\pm 1$, so one can easily evaluate $b$ given them. Note that for numerical reasons one generally uses an average of such non-bound support vectors - in particular, the solution is not exact and depends on the stopping condition for the optimization.